# c++ how to define cast operator that doesn't copy data?

Tags: c++, casting, operators

okay - maybe this is a silly question and cast operators do this already inherently..

What I have:

- some external class definition of a 4x4 Matrix
- some own 4x4 Matrix class

both classes interally simply store a float[16];

i'd like to define in my Matrix class a cast operator so that I can do things like:

```
MyMatrix4x4 m;
OtherMatrix4x4(m).someFunctionDefinedInOtherMatrix4x4();
SomeFunctionThatTakesOtherMatrix4x4(OtherMatrix4x4(m));
```

And I don't want this operator to copy any data - the functions should simply operate on the same float[16] data

How to do that?

Comment: You should be using pointers, but I'll let the C++ pros give you details.

Comment: If possible you should implement your matrix as a derivation and override some functionality instead of casting between unrelated types.

Answer (score 3):

> And I don't want this operator to copy any data - the functions should simply operate on the same float[16] data
>
> I don't want to create any data on the heap. want this to work with values on the stack - and also for convenciance i'd like to have a cast operator

Well that's not going to happen. C++'s aliasing rules pretty much forbid that.

You can use pointer-casts to do "pretend this is something else", but you can't use object casts to do that. You could cast a pointer to a stack object to a pointer to your type of object:

```
MyMatrix4x4 m;
OtherMatrix4x4 * o = (OtherMatrix4x4 *) &m;
```

However, there are two problems. First, `o` will last only as long as `m` does. It isn't an object; it's a pointer to a different object. Second, doing this is (in general) *undefined behavior* (in part due to violating aliasing: two unrelated types overlapping). Oh, odds are that it will work. But you're off the map as far as what C++ will guarantee.

This smells of a premature optimization. Do you really think that copying 16 floats is *that* big of a performance issue? If it is, then why not just use `OtherMatrix4x4` in your code instead of `MyMatrix4x4`?

Comment: What if OtherMatrix4x4 has other internal members (helpers)? What if neither class is a POD?

Comment: @Andrei: Yes. And? I'm not sure what you're trying to get at here. The OP suggests that these classes are just `float[16]`s with some methods on them. If they aren't, then what he wants is only *more* impossible.

Comment: +1 for "smells of a premature optimization" in addition to the other stuff mentioned.

Comment: Technically, he just says the "payload" is a float[16], nothing more. This is going to get ugly fast and it should be stopped sooner rather than later :)

Comment: @Andrei: I don't disagree, which is why I generally said that it's not going to work and why I put that last paragraph there.

Answer (score 1):

```
OtherMatrix4x4(m)
```

This isn't a cast operator, it's a **conversion constructor**.

Suppose the following definition of `MyMatrix4x4`:

```
struct MyMatrix4x4
{
    float x[16];
};
```

The the following should do it:

```
struct OtherMatrix4x4
{
    float* x;
    OtherMatrix4x4(MyMatrix4x4& other)
    {
       x = other.x;
    }
    void foo()
    {
       x[0] = 0;
    }
};
```

To test:

```
MyMatrix4x4 a = {{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15}};
OtherMatrix4x4(a).foo();
cout << b.x[0]; //will output 0, not 1
```

**EDIT** Here's the version where you cant edit the other matrix:

```
struct OtherMatrix4x4
{
    float x[16];
    void foo()
    {
        x[0] = 0;
    }
};

struct MyMatrix4x4
{
    float* x;
    operator OtherMatrix4x4()
    {
        OtherMatrix4x4 other;
        x = other.x;
        return other;
    }
};

MyMatrix4x4 m;
OtherMatrix4x4(m).foo();
```

Comment: mmmh - but i can't edit OtherMatrix4x4. ok - how about (OtherMatrix4x4)(m) ?

Comment: Be very very careful with this method, as this is not an owning pointer, which may make things confusing.

Comment: @MooingDuck I know, that's why I didn't write the destructor. I hope he gets the logic behind it.

Answer (score 0):

Just to present a different solution presenting inheritance. These would allow the use of code you posted above. However this is not a cast operator.

```
class MyMatrix4x4 {
public:
    float f;
};

class OtherMatrix4x4 : MyMatrix4x4  {
public:
    OtherMatrix4x4(MyMatrix4x4 &matrix)
    {
        f = matrix.f;
    }

    void someFunctionDefinedInOtherMatrix4x4();
};
```

Comment: That's still doing a copy, which is what he wanted to avoid. He really wants two objects that refer to the same memory.

Comment: @MooingDuck: You can't add members to an existing object. You can't just pretend that a `MyMatrix4x4` is an `OtherMatrix4x4`, just because it's a derived class. C++11's new standard layout rules *might* let you do it, but C++03 certainly doesn't. And you definitely can't do it the way he wants it, which is to have an object instance become a different object instance without a copy.

Comment: @NicolBolas: Yeah, didn't think that through all the way.  He either has to make a non-owning Matrix class, or do a copy.

Comment: i think inheritance is not good here, as i'm working with raw c structs and as soon as inheritance is in the play, then there is virtual function pointer stuff going on that changes the size / memory layout of the struct/class

Comment: I would not care about copying after all, as long as you pay attention that copying those not take place inside a loop. Just do it once before and once after you need the corresponding object. This should be possible.